# codeignite 3. same url different config value set for same key in single project

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have set up two domains and run on a single source code. I have setup config variable value using URL. but I have questioned if two URL hit the same time then any issue with config value.

I have created a JSON file for a particular domain. some config varibale set from there. i have create code for helper and this function call in controller __construct.

**Question :**  if two url call same time then any issue with any dynamic config variable.

```
$ci =& get_instance();  
$domain = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$filePath = '/var/www/config/'.$domain.'/ota_config.json';

$config_file = file_get_contents($filePath);
$config_binary = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x1F\x80-\xFF]/', '', $config_file);

$config_array = json_decode($config_binary, 1);

foreach ($config_array as $key => $value) {
    $ci->config->set_item($key, $value);
}
// print_r($config_array);die;  
define('CLUB_CONTACT_NO',$config_array['CLUB_CONTACT_NO']);
define('CLUB_SUPPORT_EMAIL',$config_array['CLUB_SUPPORT_EMAIL']);
define('EMAIL_CLUB_NAME',$config_array['EMAIL_CLUB_NAME']);
define('SITE_NAME', $config_array['SITE_NAME']);
```

Comment: "two url"? I don't see any urls here. "if two url call same time...any issues?" have you tested it?

Comment: i have call two different domain name like example1.com and example2.com. and using this $domain variable i have setup config value.

Comment: ok but `'/var/www/config/'.$domain.'/ota_config.json';` is a path not a url. are you asking if two different clients can access the same file at the same time? the answer is invariably yes.

Comment: no, different domain name have different ota_config.json. for two client
client 1 domain example.com then our path 'var/www/config/example.com/ota_config.json';
cline 2 domain test.com then our path '/var/www/config/test.com/ota_config.json'
but this two domain point single folder.